# Why is $||f||_p\leq (b-a)^{c_{p,q}}||f||_q$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

> **Definition:**
>
> Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and for $f\in C([a,b])$, $1\leq p
>  <\infty$ let
>
> $$||f||_p=\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^p \, dx\right)^{1/p} \text{and }  |
> |f||_\infty := \max\limits_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)|$$

**To Show:** 
$||f||_p\leq (b-a)^{c_{p,q}}||f||_q$ with  $c_{p,q}=\begin{cases}\frac{q-p}{q} \quad q<\infty ; \\ \frac{1}{p} \quad \quad q=\infty\end{cases}$

I think I already showed $q=\infty$ by using $\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^p \, dx\leq (b-a)||f||_\infty^p$ which implies that $||f||_p=\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^p \, dx\right)^{1/p}\leq (b-a)^{1/p}||f||_\infty$.

But how do I show $q<\infty$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Holder's inequality? It may give you a push in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, but I am really insecure using it...

Comment: Notice that $\frac{q-p}{q}+\frac pq=1$ and thus you may apply Holder's inequality with these as the conjugate exponentials

Comment: Write $f$ as $(1)(f)$ and apply Holder's inequality with exponents $r$ and $s$ where $r=\frac  q p$ and $s=\frac q {q-p}$.

Comment: So we have $||f||_p=\left(\int_{a}^{b}1\cdot |f(x)|^p \, dx\right)^{1/p}\leq \left(\int_{a}^{b}\cdot |f(x)|^p \, dx\right)^{q/p}\left(\int_{a}^{b}\cdot 1^{q/(q-p)} \, dx\right)^{q/(q-p)}=(b-a)^{q/(q-p)}||f||_q$?